# How to abstract the execution of a function before and after another

Tags: c#, oop

Basically I have the following design:

```cs
public class SessionManager
{
    public void BeginSession() {...}
    public void CloseSession() {...}
}

public class InvoicingService
{
    private SessionManager SessionManager { get; set; }

    public InvoicingService(SessionManager sm)
    {
         SessionManager = sm;
    }

    public void CreateInvoices(Order order)
    {
         SessionManager.BeginSession();

         // do stuff

         SessionManager.CloseSession();
    }
}
```

The issue is that I have to call `BeginSession` and `EndSession` for each action I want to do in my service(s). I've come up with some solutions to no have to consistently do that every time, but they're very overengineered and I don't like them. How would you folks address this issue? Is there any common design pattern for this?

The main thing that moved me forward to doing the session management within the services was to provide an easy to use set of classes which provide the functionality without having the consumers exploit the interface, by for example opening a session, executing multiple things, and then closing it. Or leaving the session open for too long, etc. But this is a different topic.

Comment: A helper method `DoInTransaction(Action action) { BeginSession(); action(); EndSession(); }`?

Comment: `public class CreateInvoices(Order order)` this isn't valid `class` declaration. Do all your methods accept `Order` as parameter?

Comment: @canton7 The issue is that the `action` can receive any number of parameters and can return all kinds of different types.

Comment: @JavierGarcíaManzano You can use generic `Action<T>` or `Func<T, TResult>` and specify supported parameters. Therefore I was asked you which types of parameters are accepted in your methods. Please, share rest of code with us

Comment: @JavierGarcíaManzano Sure, but you can write `void CreateInvoices(Order order) => DoInTransaction(() => SomeService.CreateInvoices(order))`. Delegates can capture variables in C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like most people suggested, I did it with a helper function:

```cs
private T RunWithinSession<T>(Func<T> func)
{
    BeginSession();
    var result = func();
    CloseSession();
    return result;
}

public Invoice CreateInvoices(Order order)
{
     return RunWithinSession(() =>
     {
          // Do stuff
          return invoice;
     });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the accepted answer is too simplistic. What if `func` breaks, but `CloseSession` is still necessary? This seems instead a perfect case for applying a Disposable pattern.

You will have to create a Disposable Session wrapper, but it will be worth the pain.

```
public class ScopedSession: IDisposable
{
    private bool disposed = false;

    public ScopedSession()
    {
        BeginSession();
    }

    public ~ScopedSession()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    public Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposed) return; 

        if (disposing) CloseSession();

        disposed = true;
    }
}

public Invoice CreateInvoices(Order order)
{
    using (var s = new ScopedSession())
    {
        // Do stuff
        return invoice;
    }
}
```

This will ensure a session is closed even if an exception is thrown.

More info at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose

EDIT: The scoped session constructor may receive an ISessionManager in input, so you can make it testable. The test case would pass a mock object implementing the interface, and yes you can hold a private reference to ISessionManager in the class and null it after closing the session.

Comment: In this case, the ScopedSession class shall contain an private instance of SessionManager. Correct?

Comment: It's a good comment on implementing disposable, but that wasn't really the question since I do have it implemented. I just tried to provide the most bare minimum example for simplicity. I'm mostly concerned about code aesthetics and patterns in this question. Also, the example you provided is quite untestable. You would have to create the `ScopedSession` outside and pass it through the constructor to isolate the classes, hence having the same issue I had before -> wrap everything in a using outside, making it very verbose, or explicitly call the session handlers.

Comment: The scoped session constructor may receive an ISessionManager in input, so you can make it testable. The test case would pass a mock object implementing the interface, and yes you can hold a private reference to ISessionManager in the class and null it after closing the session.

Answer (score 0):

Since "running with session support" is an application wide concern, you might want to look at what Aspect Oriented Programming can do for you. Please see [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/)

Another approach is to use Decorator pattern. Consider IInvoicingService interface and classes InvoicingService, InvoicingServiceWithSessionSupport (decorator wrapping InvoicingService). But this might very well increase the number of classes. Your solution with helper method seems more elegant.

Comment: Decorator is a good call! I'll give it a spin and see how it comes out. PostSharp, quite the opposite though. I think it's always a bad call to bring in dependencies without a strong reason, which this is.

Comment: @JavierGarcíaManzano Please share the code if you try with the decorator pattern